# Copy data from host to container efficiently

Tags: docker, containers

The idea is a docker container which aims to train machine learning models for computer vision.
The data which is trained needs to be uploaded to the container, consumed and deleted afterwards.

Is there any way to use a volume and transport data efficiently between the host and the container?

When I searched on the web, most sources mentioned manual transport via bash or something similar, while my application needs to do this in an automated an repeating way for different datasets.

The host machine is a windows and the container is linux.

EDIT: there is a main application running on the machine which is responsible for managing the process.

- send data to container (somehow?)
- trigger training process

the training process runs async to not block the rest api

Any ideas?

Comment: just use a docker volume. you can attach it to multiple containers and docker makes sure data is available for any host.

Comment: Can you use something like an HTTP POST request to send the data into the container?  That will work reliably across operating systems and not have any of the operational problems that come with file sharing.

Comment: @Mihai can I send data from host to a container via volume? Haven't seen something about that in the docs

Comment: @DavidMaze the data is quite large, those are image datasets and they can be quite a large amount of gigabytes. I haven't checked the latency, but it didn't feel right to me.

Comment: @Nero_f93 You don't actually send data to a container. You put it in a volume (like in a bucket) and the container picks it up from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bind mounts when building you docker container,
See https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

you specify a directory inside your container which will be mounted on a local directory on your host, this way all container write operations are mounted directly to your host directory.

I'd recommand doint it using `docker-compose`, for example below:

container directory `/opt/Projects/01_MyProject` will be mounted to host directory `/Volumes/Partition_2/Docker-Volumes/Volume_1`,

```yaml
#docker-compose.yml
...
    volumes:
      - PERSIST_DATA:/opt/Projects/01_MyProject
volumes:
  PERSIST_DATA:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /Volumes/Partition_2/Docker-Volumes/Volume_1
```

This way, you can copy anything to `/Volumes/Partition_2/Docker-Volumes/Volume_1`, which will show up under `/opt/Projects/01_MyProject`

Comment: thanks! Thats exactly what I have been looking for. Using the directory as a sync to send and cleanup datasets.